# Dynatrace with Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, dynatrace

Is there an option to use dynatrace with jenkins pipeline script? I could see options with freestyle jobs but not with pipeline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current Jenkins Plugin we provide can be used from a regular freestyle job. But - what the plugin actually does is executing the backend Test Automation REST API calls to

## 1: register a Test Run -> that returns the Test Run ID you need to pass to your tests

## 2: get Test Results -> that returns the status of the tests

Having that in mind it should be fairly easy to simply make these REST calls directly from your Pipeline Script by making these REST calls directly!

If you want to learn more about Test Automation, and the REST APIs check out some of my Jenkins based YouTube tutorials I have on my YouTube Tutorial channel: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLqt2rd0eew1bmDn54E2_M2uvbhm_WxY_6

Andi